# FTP команда NLST для SunOs(?) отдает список файлов с абсолютными путями

Tags: ftp

**Проблема:**

Есть "black box", предположительно с SunOs на борту. *Предположительно - потому, что производитель на контакт идет крайне неохотно, но косвенные признаки наличествуют.*

При смене каталога `quote CWD someDirectory` и запросе листинга директории `quote NLST`, возвращается список файлов с абсолютными путями, а у прикладного софта от этого случается несварение. 
Все доступные мне FTP-сервера, на различных операционках, возвращают список с относительными путями. С ними прикладной софт работает нормально.

**Задача:**

Найти хоть какие-то зацепки, чтобы либо пожурить производителя черного ящика и затребовать патч, либо сделать то же самое с производителем прикладного софта.

Если посмотреть в RFC, то там команда `NLST` описана таким образом, что можно толковать и так и так:

> The server will return a **stream of names of files and no other**
>   **information**.  The data will be transferred in ASCII or EBCDIC type
>   over the data connection as **valid pathname strings** separated by 
>   or .

Но, опять же, все доступные мне FTP трактуют его в пользу относительных путей. Про то, что команда может возвращать абсолютные пути, упоминается только в одной ссылке на `stackowerflow` на первые 10 страниц гугла, да и то без каких либо подробностей.

Кроме того, беглый обзор java-библиотек для работы с FTP, дает понимание, что такая ситуация никем и нигде не обрабатывается (или я не нашел).

**В чем нужна помощь:**

1. Может кто-то уже сталкивался с подобным поведением. Тогда был бы благодарен за любые подробности.
2. Если у кого есть под рукой SunOs с FTP, то очень бы помогла проверка - не ведет ли таким образом его штатный FTP.

Проще всего проверить с помощью питона.

```
# python
>>> from ftplib import FTP
>>> ftp=FTP('sunOsHost')
>>> ftp.login('login','password')   // или ftp.login() для анонимного
>>> ftp.cwd('someDirectory')
>>> ftp.retrlines('NLST')
```

Comment: Вывод комманды NLST никак не стандартизирован. Всякие парсеры в библиотеках просто смотрят по ОС, или названию сервера, и отталкиваясь от него пытаются парсить список. Вы можете попробовать использовать команду LIST, она должна отсылать чистые имена файлов, без атрибутов и дат.

Comment: @Zergatul я бы рад, но реализация захардкожена в jar-нике, который является куском грандиозной софтины от IBM. В декомпилированных исходниках видно, что никакой обработки имен файлов не происходит и оно пытается сохранять файлы as is, т.е. `/dir/file`